# How to add Scala Enumeration in SORM?

Tags: scala, sorm

How add enums in SORM?

I have this enumeration:

```scala
object RoutineType extends Enumeration {
  val TimeRoutine, SetRoutine = Value
}
```

and in DB object I add entity:

```scala
entities = Set() + Entity[RoutineType.Value]()
```

but when I load everything I get this exception:

```
Caused by: sorm.core.SormException: Unsupported type: Enumeration
```

Why? Documentation tells enums are supported

Comment: well maybe I solved, I just don't need to add enum to entities. In local it works but when I run everything in play framework I get problems with classloader: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: models.RoutineType$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SORM only needs you to register case classes as entities with it. You shouldn't do this with enums.

Concerning your problems with Play Framework, they may be caused by incompatibility with Play 2.2. SORM only supports Play 2.1 [for now](https://github.com/sorm/sorm/issues/31).

Comment: I confirm that I use play 2.2, I will try to downgrade it. Btw I hope you continue with development, SORM is so great and simple.